# Chrome issue with CSS file and form tag

Tags: css, forms, google-chrome, styles

I created a styled scroll bar, but is not working on Chrome since I created a form. I'm trying to understand why.

For the purpose of this question, I simplified the files to:
Css file (styles.css):

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 8px;
  height: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
  background-color: rgba(38, 81, 121, 0.4);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #265179;
}
```

HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>            
        <form>
            <input type="text" name="example_1" />
            <input type="text" name="example_2" />
            <input type="text" name="example_3" />
            <input type="text" name="example_4" />
            <input type="text" name="example_5" />
            <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
            <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
            <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
            <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
            <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
            <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
            <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
            <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
            <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you test this on Chrome the scroll bar will be the default one instead of the custom styled one.

If you remove 3 or 4 inputs or the form tag, the styled scroll will work again!!!

Can someone explain me why? Thks

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8uvu7/ The custom scroll bar seems to work for me on chrome.

Comment: Thank for your answer. Can you do a quick test on your PC to check if it works the same way?

Comment: Hi, can you check it here: http://sysemp.com/fiddle.html